# Why my tkinter keyboard hides the "S" key

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Ok, so i've imported the keyboard in a 2d list for the rows and columns of a standard keyboard. Im just testing it however the "S" key seems to dissapear which is very unusual as the keys are initialised in a for looop.

[Image Of "S" Key Not Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcLRM.png)

Below is my code. Thanks in advance

```
from tkinter import *

KEYS = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"], ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"], ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]]

class CharInput:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.buttons = []
        for y in range(len(KEYS)):
            for x in range(len(KEYS[y])):
                print(KEYS[y][x])
                self.buttons.append(Button(parent, text=KEYS[y][x]))
                self.buttons[len(self.buttons)-1].bind("<Button-1>", self.clicked)
                self.buttons[len(self.buttons)-1].grid(row=y, column=x)

    def clicked(self, event):
        print("clicked")
        event.widget.configure(bg="green")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    CharF = Frame().grid(row=2, column=0)
    CharInput(CharF)
    F2 = Frame(width=12, height=12).grid(row=1, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know that all the buttons are put into root window instead of frame `ChartF` because `ChartF` is `None`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the "s" key is on row 1, column 1 and you also put `F2` in row 1, column 1. `F2` is thus on top of `s`, hiding it from view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Tkinter in the slightest.. but looked like simple code and I wanted to try to solve the problem.. anyway

```
from tkinter import *

KEYS = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"], ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"], ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]]

class CharInput:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.buttons = []
        for y in range(len(KEYS)):
            for x in range(len(KEYS[y])):
                print(KEYS[y][x], x, y)
                self.buttons.append(Button(parent, text=KEYS[y][x]))
                self.buttons[len(self.buttons)-1].bind("<Button-1>", self.clicked)
                self.buttons[len(self.buttons)-1].grid(row=y, column=x)
            print("\n\n")

    def clicked(self, event):
        print("clicked")
        event.widget.configure(bg="green")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    CharF = Frame().grid(row=3, column=0)
    CharInput(CharF)
    F2 = Frame(width=12, height=12).grid(row=3, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

I changed the row= to 3 in both cases

```
CharF = Frame().grid(row=3, column=0)
        CharInput(CharF)
        F2 = Frame(width=12, height=12).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Comment: You don't need to change _both_ rows; you only need to change the row for `F2`. The problem is that `F2` is sitting on top of the key; if you change `F2`'s `row` to 0, the W key is missing. If you change it to 2, the X key is missing. Changing `F2`'s `row` to 3 will make sure that it's under the letters.